# Save data in especific rows and cols

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a script where I need to record the information inserted in the form within a specific range (A10: B17), which works very well (as long as there is no information below B17.). The problem is that starting from B19, I need to enter other information .. then the data entered in the form must be recorded and when it arrives at B17 .. it will not be possible to record more.

```js
function addNovaLinha(dadosLinha) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var rng = sheet.getRange("A10:B17");
//sheet.setActiveRange(range);
var limite = sheet.getLastRow();

var row = 9;
var col = 1;


if (limite <= 16) {


  setValueInSpreadsheet(dadosLinha.item, limite+1, col);
  setValueInSpreadsheet(dadosLinha.qtd, limite+1, col+1);
  // Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  row = row + 1;
} else {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("no more insert data here!");
}
  return true;  
}


function setValueInSpreadsheet(val, row, col) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getRange(row,col);
  var value = range.getValue();
  

  range.setValue(val);
  
}
```

[image: It´s Works]

[image: does not work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var limite = sheet.getLastRow();
```

by

```
var limite = sheet.getRange("B10:B17").getValues()
   .reduce(function(last,row,i) { 
      last = row[0] === '' ? last : 10 + i;
      return last},10);
```

The above because `getLastRow()` will return the last row used in the sheet but what you need is the position (row number) of the last cell from `B10:B17` having a value.